# How to See Required Library File Names in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I see the *required library file name*? e.g. *path/to/file.rb* or *path/to/file.so*

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.7.1)
[1] pry(main)> require "readline"
=> false
```

I would like to make sure the exact file path that is actually required, but don't know how to confirm the file path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby has a pre-defined variable `$"` or `$LOADED_FEATURES` which contains the required modules

```
$LOADED_FEATURES
#=> ["enumerator.so", "thread.rb", "rational.so", ...]
```

You could use `grep` to find "readline":

```
$LOADED_FEATURES.grep /readline/
#=> ["/Users/sos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle"]
```